# How to make my SoundCloud progress bar draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I am trying to make a SoundCloud music player. I made a seek bar for it to show the sound progress. but I would like to make it draggableby jQuery.

Here is my code for the progress bar. how can I add `draggable`?

```
SC.stream("/tracks/147310720", function (sound) {
    sound.play({
        whileplaying: function () {
            $(".seekLoad").css('width', ((sound.position / sound.duration) * 100) + '%');
        },
    });
    $(".seekBase").click(function (e) {
        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        width = $(this).width(),
        duration = sound.durationEstimate;
        sound.setPosition((x / width) * duration);
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/wBZyX/

Comment: Any luck on this? I seems like the API changed or something ---